# How to find the described circle?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, differential-geometry, low-dimensional-topology

Given a linearly connected domain $\Omega$ homeomorphic to a $2D$ disc $D^2$ with a simple regular ($C^1$ and nowhere vanishing derivative) boundary $\partial\Omega$, find such a circle $\omega(\rho, O)$ that minimizes the following sum of fractions (choose one between all ones having a non-empty intersection with $\Omega$), the condition:
($S$ stands for area)

$$\frac{S_{\omega}}{S_{\omega}+S_{\Omega\cap\omega}}+\frac{S_\Omega}{S_\Omega+S_{\Omega\cap\omega}}\rightarrow \min$$ (depiction is below)

[image: Depiction.]

Comment: What are $S_\Omega$ etc.? How is $\operatorname{min}$ a property? What are your attempts and thoughts on the problem?

Comment: @aschepler everything is depicted. $S_\Omega$ is the area of the domain without the area of the intersection with the disc, $S_\omega$ is the area of the disc without the area of the intersection, $\S_{\Omega\cap\omega}$ is the area of the intersection of the disc and the domain.
min is not a property but a condition (I don't actually know the correct word for it).
As for attempts, I don't know how to start the research.

Comment: @DenisD.Bavrin Your question is missing some words. Would you say that the following sentence has any meaning? *Find $a$ such that $\min \int_0^1 (x-a)^2dx$*

Comment: @Didier thank you very much, what about now?

Comment: The question is clear, except for one word: what does it mean "to find"? Obviously we can't expect a formula for $\rho$ and $O$ in terms of... well, there is just nothing that can serve as arguments for any kind of formula, is it?